# How to arrange / sort the elements of an array such that it matches a specific pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

### PROBLEM SETUP

I am using the following code to generate an array that contains arrays which have a given length and whose elements' sums equal to some given value (Note that repetition of digits is allowed):-

```
from itertools import product
  
def find_combinations(sum_value, len_value):
    lst = range(sum_value + 1)

    return [
        pair 
        for pair in product(lst, repeat=len_value) 
        if sum(pair) == sum_value
    ]

# ----------------------------------------- #

sum_value = # some value
len_value = # some value

print(find_combinations(sum_value, len_value))
```

For example,

If the sum, `sum_value`, is `4`, and the length, `len_value`, is `2`, the output this code produces is:-

```
[
    (0, 4),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 0),
]
```

---

### THE ACTUAL PROBLEM

This code works perfectly - it contains all the combinations that I was expecting. **But the problem here is that the order of the array is incorrect**.

That is,

In the previous example, where the required `sum` was `4`, and the `length` was `2`,
the output should have been this:-

```
[
    (4, 0),
    (0, 4),
    (3, 1),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 2),
]
```

So if the required `sum` is `4`, and the `length` is `3`, the output that this code produces is:-

```
[
    (0, 0, 4),
    (0, 1, 3),
    (0, 2, 2),
    (0, 3, 1),
    (0, 4, 0),
    (1, 0, 3),
    (1, 1, 2),
    (1, 2, 1),
    (1, 3, 0),
    (2, 0, 2),
    (2, 1, 1),
    (2, 2, 0),
    (3, 0, 1),
    (3, 1, 0),
    (4, 0, 0),
]
```

But the order of the expected output is:-

```
[
    (4, 0, 0),
    (0, 4, 0),
    (0, 0, 4),
    (3, 1, 0),
    (0, 3, 1),
    (1, 0, 3),
    (1, 3, 0),
    (0, 1, 3),
    (3, 0, 1),
    (2, 1, 1),
    ...,
]
```

So my question is, how can I arrange the elements of this array such that it matches this pattern?

---

P.S. - You can refer to the [image: Generic badge], from which this one is inspired.

Comment: What is the pattern exactly? Can you define it with some rules?

Comment: @RinkeshP Thank you for your response! In all honesty, I don't know how to define the pattern exactly, i.e., I cannot put it into words. All the information we've got here are the two examples I have provided.

Comment: Is there a particular problem which requires you to have them ordered by pattern? If there really is a pattern to this it must be extendible to larger input sizes as well. I tried to consider no of zeros, the maximum number and the position of maximum number but it couldn't match, the rules break at the 7th tuple.

Comment: I assumed the pattern was by tuple with highest number, then by the index position but that fails in example 2 with other combinations between `(3, 1, 0)` and `(3, 0, 1)`. Can you not provide more info?

Comment: "generating all partitions" Knuth TAOCP 7.2.1.4 (the twelvefold way)

Comment: Can you maybe add a sum is 5, length is 4 example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could sort the array by decreasing [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) (deviation from the elements mean):

```
sorted(all_combinations, key=lambda combi: -np.var(combi))
```

"numpy.var" calculates the variance of each element. Since the variance is the squared standard deviation, a huge outlier like 4 in (4, 0, 0) produces a huge variance. The "-" sorts in decreasing order.

If you need the same number combinations (like (4, 0, 0) and (0, 4, 0), which produces the same variance) in a specific order you could very slightly weight your elements by adding a small number to the element that should be sorted first:

```
sorted(all_combinations, key=lambda combi: -np.var(np.array(combi) + np.linspace(0.01, 0, num=len(all_combinations[0]))))
```

Comment: Thank You! That was exactly what I was looking for. If only you could explain the code, I would mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if you have further questions

Comment: I can't understand the rules described by the OP until seeing this. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Hey guys! I was not accepting this answer, or any answer for the matter, because, if you look closely, the sequence produced was not exactly the same. But as far as I am concerned, this is the closest / best answer, so far. I am waiting for 3 more days, after which, if I don't get the expected answer, I will mark this as the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this idea:

- Start from the largest possible value (to get (`sum_len`, 0, ..., 0) as the first entry)
- then, produce all possible rotations and add them to the result (I achieve this using the double ended queue structure)
- last, you keep track of the visited tuples (to avoid duplicates)

```py
import itertools
import collections

  
def find_combinations(sum_value, len_value):
    lst = range(sum_value, -1, -1)
    
    result = list()
    result_s = set()
    for pair in itertools.product(lst, repeat=len_value):
        if pair in result_s:
            continue
        
        if sum(pair) == sum_value:
            pair = collections.deque(pair)
            for i in range(len_value):
                t_pair = tuple(pair)
                if t_pair in result_s:
                    pair.rotate()
                    continue
                
                result.append(t_pair)
                result_s.add(t_pair)
                pair.rotate()
                
    return result
```